# Trying to automate the execution of 2 scripts which install IIS 7.0

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I aim to create my Powershell script to automatize the installation of IIS and all the features we needed and even found a Batch file to enable the execution of powershell scripts without having to go on "Modules -> SetExecutionPolicy ..." thus, making it easier to manage.

What I wanted to do is create a BATCH file that asks "Is script execution enabled on your machine ?" and we have 3 different answers like the following: "Yes, I have the execution enabled", "No I don't have the execution enabled" and "I don't know". Depending on the answer, the batch executes the needed files to install IIS. If the answer is number 1 only execute the .ps1 file, if answer is number 2 or 3 execute first the .bat to enable and then  the .ps1 file.

So after doing a lot of research and trying to create a script I couldn't come up with one that works. As you can see, there are a lot of errors there, but I don't have enough script knowledge to finish this. Can someone help me?

```
@ECHO OFF

:BEGIN
CLS
CHOICE /N /C:123 /M "In your system: 1 - Scripts are enabled. 2 - Scripts are disabled. 3 - I dont know (1, 2, or 3)"%1

IF ERRORLEVEL ==3 GOTO THREE
IF ERRORLEVEL ==2 GOTO TWO
IF ERRORLEVEL ==1 GOTO ONE

:THREE
CALL c:\ScriptsIIS\IISInstallation.ps1
CALL c:\ScriptsIIS\IISInstallation.ps1
ECHO Installation finished.

:TWO
CALL c:\ScriptsIIS\IISInstallation.ps1
CALL c:\ScriptsIIS\ScriptEnableExecution.bat
ECHO Installation finished.

:ONE
CALL c:\ScriptsIIS\ScriptEnableExecution.bat
ECHO Installation finished.


PAUSE
```

Can you guys please point out the errors and help me correct it ?

EDIT1: I don't get an error message, I just get an empty cmd window.

**EDIT2:** Solved the problem with a simple answer from Jubjub Bandersnatch, THANK YOU ! Sorry for the terrible code and the amount of simple error (as seen under Option 1 and 2, amongst others), I'll study more so I can come up with beter questions. Thanks guys. :))

```
cls
Powershell -noexit -command "& {Set-ExecutionPolicy remotesigned -Force}"
Powershell -File c:\ScriptsIIS\IISInstallation.ps1
```

This one should work.

Comment: The result Im getting right now is just an empty cmd window after I press " 1 ", " 2 " or " 3 ". 
I placed the goto:eof and still getting an empty cmd window after 1 press one of the options.

Comment: You can't call ps1 file from batch. You have to use powershell.exe -file script.ps1 for example

Comment: Oh, thanks, let me try it and I'll edit the code in the question. (also a mistake at the " :THREE " label that I just noticed)

Comment: You're also calling `ScriptEnableExecution.bat` only when you don't need it (option 1 and after the PowerShell script in option 2).

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, this code is terrible. End of the working day and as a newbie intern, you know, I'm just bad. haha Thanks for pointing that out, I guess I'll study a bit more before trying this kind of thing. Thank ou guys again ! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a reason to ask the user anything if what you want to know is detectable by the script?

If you only want the PoSH execution policy to be set to bypass or something all the time, why not just do that? Then, call IISInstallation.ps1.

```
PowerShell -Command "Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass"
PowerShell -File c:\ScriptsIIS\IISInstallation.ps1
```

Better still, you can not care what the policy is and still run the script.

```
PowerShell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File c:\ScriptsIIS\IISInstallation.ps1
```

Comment: Note that `-ExecutionPolicy Bypass` will fail when the execution policy is locked via group policies.

Comment: It was just to execute 1 script (in batch o prevent errors if the execution policy was disabled) who would execute both if the answer was execution policy disabled.  But you are right,  it is much easier this way. Thanks ! :))) (cant upvote you, sorry)

Comment: So I can just put "Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned" instead of bypass ?

Comment: I don't know how it behaves WRT group policy settings, but I think you can choose any legitimate value you like.